# iOS UIInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

My iOS app supports both landscape and portrait. The splash screen, login view and the home view are all portrait.

Now if I rotate the device to landscape and start the app all three views are and stay in portrait which is what is needed. But if I start the app in portrait and during splash screen I rotate the device to landscape the login screen is shown in landscape then automatically moves to portrait. Same for home screen (auto login, when user has already logged in and reopened the app, it goes directly to home screen).

I used this

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
```

in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear. I also used

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

So, what I want to achieve is to keep the views in portrait even if I rotate the device during the splash screen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the flow of the app that was causing the problem. The solutions provided by Ryan and Soberman are helpful. These lines of code should work fine
`supportedInterfaceOrientations`
`NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your `viewDidLoad` call:

```
// Change to portrait if in landscape mode
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

And remember to call super in `supportedInterfaceOrientations`

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
   [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: what should I use in the shouldAutorotate method?

Comment: I put `YES` in `shouldAutorotate`.

Comment: No it didn't work. It is rotating all the time now! it's not even autorotating!!

Comment: So it goes to landscape even when you set the `supportedInterfaceOrientation` mask to Portrait? AND what do you mean all the time? Like it just keeps rotating even when you don't do anything?

Comment: I meant the app became rotating whenever I rotate the device portrait/landscape! yes with setting the mask to portrait, the app is rotating to landscape!! no autorotating!

Comment: You have added this code to the splash screen, login view and the home view? I guess I misunderstood and you should have `shouldAutorotate` to `NO` in the splash screen. EDIT: I take it you want any view to start in portrait and the user can switch the home/login view to landscape if they wanted?

Comment: Sorry for late response. No the users shouldn't be able to rotate the three views at all even if the device is in landscape it should stay in portrait! the problem as I think is the view after the splash screen becomes landscape then rotates to portrait because I set the orientation to portrait!

Comment: @HannaB so you never want it to go to landscape? I misunderstood. Go to General settings of your app and uncheck the landscape options. Should stop the app from going to landscape mode.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. I just posted my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should override your viewController's `shouldAutorotate` method and return there `NO` in those controllers, which you don't want to rotate.

EDIT: Try comment-out the `shouldAutorotate` method and implement

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: it is not rotating at all now! it is just stuck in landscape mode!

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. I just posted my answer!